# How to use ServiceWorkerController on Android

Tags: java, android, hybrid-mobile-app

I came across [ServiceWorkerController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ServiceWorkerController) while looking through the Android WebView documentation and decided to give it a try. Unfortunately I have been unable to get intercept any calls. I am aware of [WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%2520java.lang.String)) but am interested in learning more about the ServiceWorkerController. Unfortunately the documents are a little sparse beyond what I have already implemented below. Any help would be appreciated.

I have put together a simple app consisting of a single Activity.

```
package com.example.myapplication;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ServiceWorkerClient;
import android.webkit.ServiceWorkerController;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final static String LOGTAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ServiceWorkerController.getInstance().setServiceWorkerClient(new ServiceWorkerClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebResourceRequest request) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "in service worker");
                return null;
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "about to load URL");
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

And my relevant `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the issue to be a misunderstanding. I had believed that installing a `ServiceWorkerClient` would allow for me to intercept all requests from all WebViews in my app regardless of domain. This appears to not be the case. The `ServiceWorkerClient` is only called *if* a webview has installed a ServiceWorker already. All service worker requests from all service workers are then funneled to the  `ServiceWorkerClient`. What this means is that if you wish to intercept all network requests within all webviews in your app you will also need to override `shouldInterceptRequest()` on your `WebViewClient` as well.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ServiceWorkerClient;
import android.webkit.ServiceWorkerController;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final static String LOGTAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ServiceWorkerController swController = ServiceWorkerController.getInstance();
        swController.setServiceWorkerClient(new ServiceWorkerClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebResourceRequest request) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "in service worker. isMainFrame:"+request.isForMainFrame() +": " + request.getUrl());
                return null;
            }
        });
        swController.getServiceWorkerWebSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                                              WebResourceRequest request) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "in webview client. isMainFrame:"+request.isForMainFrame() +": " + request.getUrl());
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
            }
        });
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "about to load URL");

        //service worker handler only invoked on pages with service workers
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```